# How can i change properties in application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, properties

Could anyone advice any way how the properties in application.properties can be changed on application startup? On application start i can receive some propertied from DB that should override my appropriate properties at file. My goal is tho change them only once on app start... 
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a launcher for the program ? It will be the launcher responsibility to locate and use appropriate properties ? So when the launcher program starts you will check via DB connection for new properties install the properties on the appropriate location and then launch your real program.

Comment: sounds reasonable, but a bit large task... i need only to change few properties in application.properties somehow...